# Unable to connect to online activemq

Tags: python, amazon-mq

I am unable to connect to Amazon MQ. This is my code:

```py
import time
import sys
import os
import stomp
from stomp import *
#import pika

user = os.getenv("admin")
password = os.getenv("password")
host = os.getenv("stomp+ssl://online_host:61614")
port = os.getenv("61614")
destination = sys.argv[1:2] or ["/topic/event"]
destination = destination[0]

messages = 1000
data = "Hello World from Python"
conn = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports=[(host, port)])
#conn.set_listener('print', PrintingListener())
#conn.start()
conn.connect(login=user, passcode=password)

for i in range(0, messages):
    conn.send(data, destination=destination, persistent='false')

conn.send("SHUTDOWN", destination=destination, persistent='false')

conn.disconnect(receipt=None)
```

Can you please help me out? I am getting an error as:

```
Could not connect to host None, port None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\navee\PycharmProjects\apachekafka\venv\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 730, in attempt_connection
    self.socket = socket.create_connection(host_and_port, self.__timeout)
  File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Could not connect to host None, port None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\navee\PycharmProjects\apachekafka\venv\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 730, in attempt_connection
    self.socket = socket.create_connection(host_and_port, self.__timeout)
  File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Could not connect to host None, port None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\navee\PycharmProjects\apachekafka\venv\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 730, in attempt_connection
    self.socket = socket.create_connection(host_and_port, self.__timeout)
  File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 787, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\navee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 914, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "act_prod.py", line 20, in <module>
    conn.connect(login=user, passcode=password)
  File "C:\Users\navee\PycharmProjects\apachekafka\venv\lib\site-packages\stomp\connect.py", line 161, in connect
    self.transport.start()
  File "C:\Users\navee\PycharmProjects\apachekafka\venv\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 104, in start
    self.attempt_connection()
  File "C:\Users\navee\PycharmProjects\apachekafka\venv\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 803, in attempt_connection
    raise exception.ConnectFailedException()
stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logged error:

> 'Could not connect to host None, port None'

It looks like your env vars for host and port do not exist.

besides,

you should call conn.set_ssl when communicating over ssl

```
conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[(host, port)])
```

and also set wait arg when connecting, so you won't try to send before connected successfuly

```
conn.connect(login=user, passcode=password, wait=True)
```